# how to include a file in module rust in vim

Tags: rust, neovim

Whenever I create a new rust file in neovim it says that it is not a part of module tree and I get a bunch of errors. The weird thing is it eventually it just starts working but that is not good enough so my question is how to manually add files to the module tree in vim.

I have tried restarting vim and reinstalling coc rust but nothing has worked.

Comment: There should be nothing specific about vim. For the file to be included it has to mentioned somewhere in the hierarchy. Usually it starts from main.rs or lib.rs and then goes dows with mod.rs files if you use folders. or just mod keyword if other files are in the same folder

Comment: then why is it that when I try "use super::<filename>" it does not work?

Comment: use crate::<filename>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For files to be part of the module tree they have to be mentioned in the hierarchy somewhere i.e.:

```rust
// my_mod.rs
pub fn some_code() {}

// lib.rs or main.rs
mod my_mod; // without this line you will get the error
```

If the file is mentioned and the error still persists sometimes the state in `rust_analyzer` gets out of sync and a restart of it should resolve it.